# I HAVE TO CONVERT A FOLDER CONTAINING 1010 FOLDERS WITH A MIXTURE OF XML,JSON,TEXT FILES TO .CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

[enter image description here][1]I have to convert a folder containing 1010 folders with a mixture of `XML`, `JSON`, `TEXT` files to `.CSV` file.
my CODE

```py
# Import Module
import pandas
import os
json_file_path = "//Users//ruzi//Desktop//top1000_complete"
csv_file_path = "//Users//ruzi//Desktop//output.csv"
          
if os.path.isdir(json_file_path):
     for e in os.listdir(json_file_path):
          new_path=json_file_path+"//"+str(e)
          if str(e) != '.DS_Store'and os.path.isdir(new_path):
              for e1 in os.listdir(new_path):
                  next_new_path = new_path + "//" + str(e1)
                  if str(e1) != '.DS_Store'and os.path.isdir(next_new_path):
                      for e2 in os.listdir(next_new_path):
                          final_path = next_new_path + "//" + str(e2)
                          if str(e2) != '.DS_Store'and os.path.isfile(final_path):
                              f=open(final path,"rt")

# Read Json File
data_frame = pandas.read_json(json_file_path)

# Convert Into CSV
data_frame.to_csv(csv_file_path, index = None)
```

The full source code is shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iED9.png

The 1010 folders looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j8l8.png

Inside each 1010 folder
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQnKE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `NotADirectory` error.
You should first examine if the path is a directory or not.

```py
import os

#checks if path is a file
is_file = os.path.isfile(file_path)

#checks if path is a directory
is_directory = os.path.isdir(file_path)
```

Do something like this to check whether the path is a directory or a file:

```py
import pandas
import os

json_file_path = "//Users//ruzi//Desktop//top1000_complete"
csv_file_path = "//Users//ruzi//Desktop//output.csv"

if os.path.isdir(json_file_path):
   for e in os.listdir(json_file_path):
      new_path = json_file_path+"//"+str(e)
      if str(e) != '.DS_Store' and os.path.isdir(new_path):
         for e1 in os.listdir(new_path):
             next_new_path = new_path + "//" + str(e1)
             if str(e1) != '.DS_Store' and os.path.isdir(next_new_path):
                for e2 in os.listdir(next_new_path):
                    final_path = next_new_path + "//" + e2
                    if str(e2) != '.DS_Store' and os.path.isfile(final_path):
                       f = open(final_path,"rt")
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error msg when I read the JSON file to .csv

Comment: please add the error you are getting to the question, so I can see